# Link is not getting clicked if parent div has click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia

I have a div which has a trigger click associated with it. Inside that div there is another div in which I have binded html using innerhtml.bind(Aurelia). That HTML part contains anchor tag. Now when I am clicking on the link nothing is happening. It is not opening the link.

My HTML structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<div click.trigger="someMethod()">
   <div>
      <div innerhtml.bind="">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help in what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `click.delegate` instead of `click.trigger`?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne tried but no luck

Comment: you just have to `return true;` from your `someMethod()`. so aurelia will not call `perventDefault`

Comment: Here is the specific part in the doc that you can consult. Basically what avrahamcool said, but with more links and extra content https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#dom-events